# How can I retrieve the meta-information of all patents filed to the USPTO by a given assignee?

Tags: uspto, databases, api

How can I retrieve the meta-information of all patents filed by a given assignee?

I am mostly interested in title, inventor list, and year of filing, for patents filed to the USPTO. The meta-information should be in some machine-readable format (i.e., querying Google Patents like https://patents.google.com/?assignee=Adobe+Systems+Inc&oq=assignee:(Adobe+Systems+Inc) isn't helpful for my use case as the output isn't machine-friendly).

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- http://qr.ae/TUpdhd

Comment: Please have a look around, there are plenty questions about patent apis, maybe one of those helps already (consider making this a duplicate or compiling a self-answer if it's no duplicate).

Comment: @DonQuiKong ok I  self-answered

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google Patents Public Datasets](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/10/google-patents-public-datasets-connecting-public-paid-and-private-patent-data) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180708195714/https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/10/google-patents-public-datasets-connecting-public-paid-and-private-patent-data)), which can be accessed through Google BigQuery.

For example, [this query](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/savedquery/931482164662:3bac9e5fe26649fdb600fd123da0be53) (its execution is free of charge):

```
#legacySQL
SELECT publication_number, assignee_harmonized.name, filing_date, country_code  
FROM [patents-public-data.patents.publications]
-- WHERE UPPER(assignee_harmonized.name) LIKE 'ADOBE%'
WHERE UPPER(assignee_harmonized.name) = 'ADOBE SYSTEMS INC'
ORDER BY filing_date DESC 
LIMIT 20000;
```

returns:

[image]

To retrieve the inventor names, you can run:

```
#legacySQL
SELECT publication_number, inventor_harmonized.name, filing_date
FROM [patents-public-data.patents.publications] 
WHERE publication_number IN (
  SELECT publication_number FROM [patents-public-data.patents.publications] 
  -- WHERE UPPER(assignee_harmonized.name) LIKE 'ADOBE%'
  WHERE UPPER(assignee_harmonized.name) = 'ADOBE SYSTEMS INC'
)
AND country_code = 'US'
ORDER BY filing_date DESC;
```

Schema description: https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/patents-public-data:patents.publications?tab=schema:

[image]

I have used the [legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql), but the preferred query syntax for BigQuery is standard SQL. See  [Migrating to Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#comparison_of_legacy_and_standard_sql) if you want to convert the queries to Standard SQL.